# Criteria API: filter by class type

Tags: java, sql, jpa-2.0, jpql, criteria-api

I'm relativley new to relational databases and I have some problems concerning the creation of queries. First I want to explain the situation shortly. I have several entity classes. All of them extend `AbstractEntity` or `EntityProperty`. So entities can have properties and properties have owning entities, so there is a bidirectional relation.
Now let's say `ConcreteEntity` extends `AbstractEntity` and I want to create queries like this: Get all entities of type `ConcreteEntity` which has at least on property with a name contained in the given list `propertyNames`. Until now I have the following working criteria query:

```
CriteriaQuery<AbstractEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(AbstractEntity.class);
Root<EntityProperty> property = cq.from(EntityProperty.class);
Join<EntityProperty, AbstractEntity> entity = property.join(EntityProperty_.owningEntities);
cq.where(property.get(EntityProperty_.name).in((Object[]) propertyNames));
cq.select(entity);
```

But now I want only those entities of type `ConcreteEntity`. How could I achieve this?
In JPQL I wrote "SELECT entity FROM EntityProperty property JOIN property.owningEntities entity" and here I also have no idea how to write it in the way that only a specific type is returned...

Thanks for answers in advance!

EDIT: moved the second question to [criteria query: indistinct result lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237579/criteria-query-indistinct-result-lists) and removed distinct in the code (that didn't work)

Comment: what if you had this query parametrized using generics? Then you could say if you want AbstractEntity or ConcreteEntity in compilation time (not sure if this makes sense)

Comment: I can do that when I define the entities as root. Then I can axplicitly definie the class. The problem here is that I access the entities via the attribute `owningEntities` of the fitting properties. And that attribute has the type List<AbstractEntity>.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but just in case someone stumbles upon the same problem, here is how it can be solved.
You can easily filter by entity type like this:

```
Predicate p = cb.equal(entity.type(), cb.literal(ConcreteEntity.class));
```

where **entity** can be a Path (Root and Join included), **cb** is a CriteriaBuilder object. So in your case it would be something like this:

```
CriteriaQuery<AbstractEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(AbstractEntity.class);
Root<EntityProperty> property = cq.from(EntityProperty.class);
Join<EntityProperty, AbstractEntity> entity = property.join(EntityProperty_.owningEntities);
cq.where(cb.and(
    property.get(EntityProperty_.name).in((Object[]) propertyNames),
    cb.equal(entity.type(), cb.literal.ConcreteEntity.class)
));
cq.select(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found until now was to create an enumeration with a value for each class The resulting criteria query is

```
CriteriaQuery<AbstractEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(AbstractEntity.class);
Root<EntityProperty> property = cq.from(EntityProperty.class);
SetJoin<EntityProperty, AbstractEntity> entity =
                property.join(EntityProperty_.owningEntities);
cq.where(property.get(EntityProperty_.name).in((Object[]) propertyNames),
                entity.get(AbstractEntity_.entityType).in(suitableSubTypes));
cq.select(entity);
List<AbstractEntity> resultList = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

As you can see, every entity now has the attribute entityType. I also have to create the collection suitableSubTypes every time. Another problem is that the returned type is `List<AbstractEntity>`. What I wanted was a method signature like

```
public static <T extends AbstractEntity> List<T>
                getEntities(Class<T> entityClass, String... propertyNames)
```

but for now I have

```
public static List<AbstractEntity>
                getEntities(Collection<AbstractEntityType> suitableSubTypes,
                String... propertyNames)
```

So I still hope there exists a better solution...