# criteria query: indistinct result lists

Tags: java, sql, jpa-2.0, jpql, criteria-api

I have 2 little problems. Let's say I have an entity class called `MyEntity`. This class has two kinds of properties. Therefore I have two different class `Property1` and `Property2` which are also entity classes. There are bidirectional relations betweens `MyEntity` and the property classes, especially `Property1` has an attribute `List<MyEntity> owningEntities` and `Property2` has the attribute `MyEntity owningEntity`. Now I have the following query:

```
SELECT e FROM Property1 p JOIN p.owningEntities e WHERE p.name IN :propertyNames
```

This query returns all entities that has a property of the first type with at least one of the given names. But in general the returned list is indistinct. The problem is that the SELECT DISTINCT downs't work here, at least with criteria API - I didn't try it with jpql. The code for the criteria query looks as follows:

```
CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
Root<Property1> property = cq.from(Property1.class);
SetJoin<Property1, MyEntity> entity =
                property.join(Property1_.owningEntities);
cq.where(property.get(Property1_.name).in((Object[]) propertyNames));
cq.select(entity);
// cq.select(entity).distinct(true); --> runtime error
List<MyEntity> resultList = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Is there any way to get a distict result list? I can simply convert the list into a set, but it seems ineffective to extract the same results multiple times.

The next problem is, of course I want all entities that has a property of the any type with at least one of the given names. Until now I have two queries and afterwards I merge the results. But again I extract many results multiple times. So, is there any way to combine the following two queries in an effective way?

```
SELECT e FROM Property1 p JOIN p.owningEntities e WHERE p.name IN :propertyNames  
SELECT e FROM Property2 p JOIN p.owningEntity e WHERE p.name IN :propertyNames
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How `propertyNames` is defined?

Comment: obviously it's an array...

Comment: You should get compilation error at `SetJoin<Property1, MyEntity> entity = ...` since `Property1` entity defines `List<MyEntity> owningEntities` and the _static metamodel_ is used.

Comment: Maybe we should explain that to my compiler, he seems not to be aware of that... Jokes apart, the above code works without any error. Is your point that, it should be an ListJoin? I have no idea why, but the join method returns a SetJoin object, although owningEntites IS a list.

Comment: Your compiler seems to be a badass as opposed to my therefore I am not able reproduce the problem. Using `Set` with `SetJoin` or `List` with `Listjoin` are preferred approaches ([how to choose a proper one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562673/onetomany-list-vs-set-difference)) however I am not sure if it helps with this particular error. Could you please paste stack trace from runtime error anyway?